# Why did Lord Vishnu murder King Bali?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, avatars

We know that King Bali wanted to become more powerful than Indradev . But he was  very famous in public for his kindness . Then

> 1.Why Lord Vishnu murdered King Bali in his Vaman Avatar?
>
> 2. After killing him why Lord Vishnu asked to King Bali's followers to worship their leader ( as Balipratipada I.e.one of the day in Dipavali festival) ?

Comment: Who told you Lord Vishnu killed Bali ? He is king of Patala(Rasatala Loka) at present. He is going to be next Indra in next Manvantara ie. In Sarvani Manvantar...

Comment: Lord Vishnu didn't kill Bali. [Vishnu Pushed Mahabali to nether worlds](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10547/3500).

Comment: **Duplicate + wrong premises.**